# Docker run command with environment variables

Tags: docker

I'm trying to launch a docker container that will execute a command like this:

```
docker run --net="host" -it --entrypoint bash $KAFKA_DOCKER_IMAGE "\$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic $1 --partitions $num_partitions --replication-factor $replication_factor"
```

Where $KAFKA_DOCKER_IMAGE, $replication_factor and $num_partitions are variables defined in a script that I'm using to execute this command. And $KAFKA_HOME is an environment variable that is already defined in the docker image.

My problem is that the command that is being executed on the container is the following:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic popota --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

It doesn't expand the $KAFKA_HOME.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to supply the environment variables using the -e flag

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Comment: The variable is already defined in the dockerfile. See here https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka/blob/master/kafka/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
docker run --net="host" -it --entrypoint bash $KAFKA_DOCKER_IMAGE -c "\$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic $1 --partitions $num_partitions --replication-factor $replication_factor"
```